# Plotting the bipolar neutrino oscillations in supernova

Tags: neutrinos, supernova

everyone. I am trying to study the neutrino oscillation in a core collapse supernova. In certain situations neutrinos in supernova can undergo what is called a "bipolar" oscillation. According to literature, in 2 neutrino approximation the equation takes the form of two coupled ordinary vector differential equation. [Eqn 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0608695]

$\partial_t \vec{P} = [\omega \vec{B} + \mu (\vec{P}-\vec{\bar{P}})]\times \vec{P}$

$\partial_t \vec{\bar{P}} = [-\omega \vec{B} + \mu (\vec{P}-\vec{\bar{P}})]\times \vec{\bar{P}}$.

I tried to solve these equation using Runge-Kutta method of order 4. My code in Python look like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h=0.1

s1z=[]
s2z=[]
theta0=0.01
R=10
omega=1

s1=np.array([0,0,1.])
s2=np.array([0,0,-1.]
B=[np.sin(2*theta0),0,-np.cos(2*theta0)]

for i in range(10000):
    print(s1)
    k1=h*(omega*np.cross(B,s1)+R*np.cross(-s2,s1))
    j1=h*(-omega*np.cross(B,s2)+R*np.cross(s1,s2))
    k2=h*(omega*np.cross(B,s1+k1/2)+R*np.cross(-s2-j1/2,s1+k1/2))
    j2=h*(-omega*np.cross(B,s2+j1/2)+R*np.cross(s1+k1/2,s2+j1/2))
    k3=h*(omega*np.cross(B,s1+k2/2)+R*np.cross(-s2-j2/2,s1+k2/2))
    j3=h*(-omega*np.cross(B,s2+j2/2)+R*np.cross(s1+k2/2,s2+j2/2))
    k4=h*(omega*np.cross(B,s1+k3)+R*np.cross(-s2-j3,s1+k3))
    j4=h*(-omega*np.cross(B,s2+j3)+R*np.cross(s1+k3,s2+j3))
    s1+=1/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
    s2+=1/6*(j1+2*j2+2*j3+j4)
    s1z.append(s1[2])
    s2z.append(s2[2])

plt.plot(s2z)
```

Here, s1 and s2 are the two polarisation vectors $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{\bar{P}}$. $R$ is the constant $\mu$. However, it does not give me the desired plot (fig 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0608695). This plot is a very well established plot and I am misunderstanding something here. I would be grateful if anyone please can help me to point out where I am going wrong.